# sonatabundle installation ApplicationSonataMediaBundle not found

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I tried to follow  the tutorial installation for SonataBundle [tutorial](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/installation.html)

I change only mapping in this way

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
                    SonataMediaBundle: ~
```

the command

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataMediaBundle
```

generate in `src/Application/Sonata/MediaBundle/ApplicationSonataMediaBundle`

but always I get this error :

> Class 'Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\ApplicationSonataMediaBundle' not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonata-admin Bundle installation. Class SonataCoreBundle not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227123/sonata-admin-bundle-installation-class-sonatacorebundle-not-found)

Comment: i don't think is the same problem